# "All Staff" or just "Staff"?

Tags: word-usage

In my application, I have a menu item that goes to a page where all employees along with their job titles are listed hierarchically.

Should I name this menu item "All Staff", or just "Staff"? is "All" obsolete/unnecessary?

Comment: _All_ is unnecessary/superfluous (not _obsolete_, which means 'out of date').

Comment: It depends. If you want to emphasise that it's a list of all staff then do so. Maybe there are lists with some of the staff too, or maybe other systems do something similar. This looks a matter of opinion (or writing advice which is also off-topic): I can't think of any language where you'd be accused of bad grammar for doing something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Staff' is an uncountable noun (albeit with the usual exceptions). It refers to the *entire group of people employed* by an organization or company. As it is inclusive, saying '*all* staff' could be a redundancy in some contexts. However, it is by no means unusual. In large organisations, there can be many sub-groups of staff. For example, there might be human resources, management, operations, IT etc. In communications, it might be necessary to address '*all staff*' to ensure everybody understands it applies to everyone, not just to staff within their own department.

Having said that, a better title for a page that lists all staff might be "Staff Directory".

Comment: Thank you, you made it clear. I'm wondering why my question is downvoted though.

Comment: @Mephisto Can't tell you - I didn't downvote it. But some have also voted to close it on the basis that you could have used a dictionary. I wouldn't have answered if I agreed.